# How can I add a git subtree repository without LFS files to a container repository with tracking LFS files?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-subtree

I have a repository with tracked files do git-lfs (e.g. files with pattern *.png).

Then I want to add a subtree repository that also contains *.png files, but I don't want to track that files to git-lfs, to keep the subtree repository intact.

How can I do that?

##### EDIT:

As pointed by bk2204 in the comments below, subtrees seems to have problems with git-lfs. Specially when the subtree node has lfs files. The two issues [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1948) and [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/854) bring some information.

I've tried the following procedure with a subtree node **without** lfs inside a repository with lfs.

I would like to know if someone could confirm this simple procedure really works. I'm not having troubles so far (but I made backups)

---

1. First, I edited the `.gitattributes` file including a line to not track files inside a future folder, that will contain the subtree node.

```
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
futurefoldername/** -filter=lfs -diff=lfs -merge=lfs -text
```

2. Then, I add the subtree in that folder:

```
git remote add <remote-name> <url>
git subtree add -P futurefoldername <remote-name> master
```

3. Now, LFS does not change files inside `futurefoldername` and it seems to be fine to pull and push with `git subtree` without LFS files.

---

Comment: In general, Git LFS has known problems with git-subtree.  I wouldn't recommend using git-subtree if you also want to use Git LFS.  A submodule would be a better approach.

Comment: What kind of problems can happen if I use a "Sub" repository with LFS in an "container" repository that uses LFS? I'm not very used to submodules.

Comment: If you use submodules, everything will work.  They're essentially two separate repositories with a link from the parent to the child.  If you use subtrees, then you'll run into problems like this: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1948.  We've seen a bunch of cases where git-subtree does things that literally cannot work with LFS.